# C++ to communicate to Python function

Tags: python, c++, dll

I am new to c++,

I created DLL which contains Class, and functions and all the return type of each function is PyObject (Python Object), So now i want to write the C++ application which loads DLL dynamically using LoadLibrary function.

Able to execute with adding the project to same solution and adding the reference to DLL.

I am able to load the DLL, but when i am calling the function it returns PyObject data type, how to store the return type of PyObject in C++?

Comment: you can take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), this can be a good starting point http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Python's documentation on [Concrete Objects Layer](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/concrete.html). Basically you have to convert `PyObject` into a C++ type using a function of the form `Py*T*_As*T*(PyObject* obj)` where `T` is the concrete type you want to retrieve.

The API assumes you know which function you should call. But, as stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/concrete.html), you can check the type before use:

> ...if you receive an object from a Python program and you are not sure that it has the right type, you must perform a type check first; for example, to check that an object is a dictionary, use [`PyDict_Check()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_Check).

Here is an example to convert a `PyObject` into `long`:

```
PyObject* some_py_object = /* ... */;

long as_long(
    PyLong_AsLong(some_py_object)
);

Py_DECREF(some_py_object);
```

Here is another, more complicated example converting a Python [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/list.html) into a `std::vector`:

```
PyObject* some_py_list = /* ... */;

// assuming the list contains long

std::vector<long> as_vector(PyList_Size(some_py_list));

for(size_t i = 0; i < as_vector.size(); ++i)
{
    PyObject* item = PyList_GetItem(some_py_list, i);

    as_vector[i] = PyLong_AsLong(item);

    Py_DECREF(item);
}

Py_DECREF(some_py_list);
```

A last, more complicated example, to parse a Python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/dict.html) into a `std::map`:

```
PyObject* some_py_dict = /* ... */;

// assuming the dict uses long as keys, and contains string as values

std::map<long, std::string> as_map;

// first get the keys
PyObject* keys = PyDict_Keys(some_py_dict);

size_t key_count = PyList_Size(keys);

// loop on the keys and get the values
for(size_t i = 0; i < key_count; ++i)
{
    PyObject* key = PyList_GetItem(keys, i);
    PyObject* item = PyDict_GetItem(some_py_dict, key);

    // add to the map
    as_map.emplace(PyLong_AsLong(key), PyString_AsString(item));

    Py_DECREF(key);
    Py_DECREF(item);
}

Py_DECREF(keys);
Py_DECREF(some_py_dict);
```

Comment: How to parse dict type?

Comment: If the values contains the combinations of string,dict and list then?

Comment: You can check the wrapped type of the `PyObject` using `PyString_Check()`, `PyList_Check()`, and `PyDict_Check()`. You will then have to use the correct conversion according to the checking results. You will also have to either use a `std::map` per key/value combination, or use a type erasure like `std::variant` or `std::any` (only available in C++17).

Comment: Thanks :) wasthishelpful

Comment: Hi This was very helpful, but if i want to display json string or dictionary in json tree format on console?

Comment: Looks like a different question :) Ask a new one describing what you have done, and what you want to achieve